# SQL Deny select doesnt work on databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have enables sql acl on our databrick cluster and I am trying to deny any slect on one table from my personal user using below commands

```
%sql
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES on database default from `myuser@org.com`;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES on default.billingsilver from `myuser@org.com`;
deny SELECT ON ANY FILE to `myuser@org.com`;
deny select on database default to `myuser@org.com`;
deny select on default.billingsilver to `myuser@org.com`;
show grant on default.billingsilver;
```

The result of above is as follow:

[image]
But when I run below commands

```
%sql
select count(*) from default.billingsilver;
```

I still can get the count from above table while this should deny me from running the query.

Please noe that I have logged in using `myuser@org.com` which belongs to admins in the group folder.
Can someone tell me why I still can get the count while I have denied all select on both database and the table?

Answer (score 0):

There is no **ActionType** `OWN`, in your privileges means the object does not have an owner.

To perform this GRANT, DENY (SQL operations) operations some privileges are required.

```
`DENY`: `OWN` on the object.
```

To perform this you should be the owner of the object, make sure you are the owner of the object.

**Reference:** [Operations and privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/table-acls/object-privileges#operations-and-privileges)